# List of PIE words for occupations

Tags: proto-indo-european

What are the known reconstructions of PIE words for occupations?

I composed some, but want a greater list:

- *h₃rḗǵ-s - king
- *dúk-s - military leader, commander
- *u̯iḱ-pót-i-s - village leader
- *pr̥h₂-wó-s - elder, judge
- *mén-tōr - advisor, thinker
- *pekʷ-tōr - cook
- *péh₂-s-tōr - shepherd
- *tétḱ-ōn - carpenter
- *h₂n̥tbʰi-kʷol-os (?) - helper, servant

from comments:

- *gʷou̯-kʷol-os - cowherd

Comment: You need to get a copy of [Buck's _A Dictionary of Selected Synonyms in the Principal Indo-European Languages_](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_Dictionary_of_Selected_Synonyms_in_the.html?id=Bm686HXZj_8C). It's organized by topic, including rulership.

Comment: @jlawler worth noting that the dictionary predates the total acceptance of the laryngeal theory and so its reconstructions are presented in "traditional" form without laryngeals and so it needs some translation into a more modern framework. Mallory & Adams in either their Encyclopedia of Indo-European Culture or the Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World provide plenty of modern laryngeal reconstructions in this semantic field

Comment: minor caveat to Mallory & Adams is that some of their reconstructions are based only on a few branches, possibly from a specific region, and so some of them may not actually be valid at the PIE stage

Comment: I don’t know of a specific list for occupations (is ‘king’ or ‘thinker’ really an occupation?), but I’d say at the very least you’re missing _*gʷou̯kʷolos_ ‘cowherd’.